# Julia relative path and importing custom modules

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia.
I'm really confused with using custom modules.
Note: I'm working via `vim`, not `Juno`.

For example, this is my directory tree (please ignore the `tmp.txt`).

```
.
├── algorithm
│   └── controller.jl
├── debug.jl
├── main.jl
├── model
│   └── aerospace_systems.jl
└── tmp.txt

2 directories, 5 files
```

I usually write main functions in `main.jl` and import (using) modules from other directories, e.g., `algorithm` and `model`.

In my case, there are a few annoying problems:

1. If I want to use module `Controller` in `algorithm/controller.jl` (suppose there exists) at `model/aerospace_system.jl`, then it seems that I have to add `include("../algorithm/controller.jl")` in `model/aerospace_system.jl` even I execute functions in `main.jl`.
2. After import the module `Controller` as
   `include("../algorithm/controller.jl"); using .Controller` in `model/aerospace_system.jl`,
   I cannot directly use a contained functions, e.g., `nocontrol` in `Controller`.
   In this case, I run commands in Julia REPL as follows:

```
julia> includet("main.jl")  # using Revise
julia> run_main()
ERROR: UndefVarError: nocontrol not defined
...
```

So my questions are...
Q1) How to resolve the above issue?
Q2) Is there any way to avoid such confusing relative paths? (can fix a path independent of codes' location?)

Here are brief codes related to the issue, hope it would be helpful:

1. `main.jl`

```
includet("model/aerospace_systems.jl")

using DynamicalSystems
using .AerospaceSystems
using Plots
ENV["GKSwstype"]="nul"  # do not show figures automatically

function simulate_linear(x0; T=10., dt=0.01)
    system = linearsystem(x0=x0)
    traj = trajectory(system, T, dt=dt)
    ts = 0:dt:T
    return ts, traj
end

function draw_plot(ts, traj)
    p = plot(ts, traj,
             xlabel="t (s)", label=["x1" "x2" "x3"], linewidth=1.5)
    save_path = "data/plot.pdf"
    save_dir = dirname(save_path)
    if !isdir(save_dir)
        mkdir(save_dir)
    end
    savefig(p, save_path)
end

function run_main()
    ## main
    x0 = 10*ones(3)
    ts, traj = simulate_linear(x0)
    ## plot
    draw_plot(ts, traj)
end
```

2. `model/aerospace_systems.jl`

```
module AerospaceSystems
export linearsystem

using Debugger
using StaticArrays
using DynamicalSystems
const CDS = ContinuousDynamicalSystem

include("../algorithm/controller.jl")
import .Controller

function linearsystem(;x0=zeros(3), controller=nocontrol)
    lineardynamics_with_controller(x, p, t) = lineardynamics(x, p, t; controller=controller)
    return CDS(lineardynamics_with_controller, x0, nothing)
end
```

3. `algorithm/controller.jl`

```
module Controller
export nocontrol, negativelinearfeedback

using LinearAlgebra

function nocontrol(x, t; dim=1)
    return zeros(dim, 1)
end

function negativelinearfeedback(x, t; K=I)
    return -K*x
end

end
```

Comment: Hey Jinrae, I have a similar setup for some projects. What I did was create a package itself (see PackageTemplate.jl) and then import/include all the modules and files there. Then, in other places where you want to use any of the code you wrote, you just do using “the name of the package” and it brings in all your code!

Comment: @logankilpatrick Thanks, I'll take a look at the package :)

Comment: @logankilpatrick Sorry but I still don't understand it...
e.g., I generated my own pkg `MyPkg` by `PkgTemplates.jl`. Then, there is a file `MyPkg/src/MyPkg.jl` and `MyPkg/test/runtests.jl`.
In `MyPkg/test/runtests.jl`, `using MyPkg` does not occur an error. However, if I make a file `MyPkg/src/OtherModule.jl` and `using OtherModule` reports errors (Julia said there is no such module). What am I mistaking?

Comment: Ummmmm...
Probably I got it.
Generate several packages, and use the packages by `using names` natually import them. Thanks!

Comment: JinraeKim / @logankilpatrick - would one of you two like to answer the question formally, or is it okay if I do it?