# Manage custom packages and projects

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia.

I'm seeking the best practice of structuring directories, packages, and projects.

Compared with Python, the most annoying parts in Julia are as follows:

1. The path for e.g. `include` seems depend on the path of executed file. I'd like to keep a specific reference path so that I can load some files easily.
2. I asked similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770593/julia-relative-path-and-importing-custom-modules?noredirect=1#comment112767852_63770593), and someone told me that creating packages and using `using` will be easy to manage my projects.
   However, It's really confusing when loading files and modules. For example,

```
MyProject
├── MyPkg1
│   ├── src
│   │   └── MyPkg1.jl
│   └── test
│       └── runtests.jl
└── MyPkg2
    ├── src
    │   └── MyPkg1.jl
    └── test
        └── runtests.jl

6 directories, 4 files
```

a) `MyPkg1/src/MyPkg1.jl`

```
module MyPkg1

export func_export

function func_export
    println("hi")
end

end
```

b) `MyPkg1/test/runtests.jl`

```
using MyPkg1
using Test

@testset "MyPkg1.jl" begin
    func_export()  # raise error: func_export not defined
end
```

c) `MyPkg2/test/runtests.jl`

```
using MyPkg2
using Test
using MyPkg1  # other Pkg

@testset "MyPkg2.jl" begin
    func_export()  # raise error
end
```

As written in the above codes, some errors are raised (see b), c)).

So my questions are...

1. If I did something wrong in the above example, please explain why errors occur in detail.
2. What's the best practice in developing Julia projects in the sense of directory structure?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a typo, but `func_export` needs to be defined with parenthesis: `function func_export() ...`

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. I'm not sure that it makes error disappeared because the codes are actually illustrative things.

Comment: It would make the error disappear. If you ask for a specific error the code can't be "illustrative".